# Custom HTMLElement component testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I've created a custom component by extending the HTMLElement class and used shadowDOM to attach it, following this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements

Now, I want to test my component, run unit tests, test the component buttons  listeners...

What tools shall I use for this? because everywhere I search for component testing, I end-up with results about testing Angular components with Jasmine, or Reactjs with Jest, 
but in my case I'm not using Angular or React, it's a custom component with a shadowDOM.

Thanks

Comment: You are still testing DOM in the end.  The same set of tools will meet your needs.